# Multiplexer CD4067 bug:signal appears in unselected channels

Tags: multiplexer

I connected a multiplexer CD4067 with arduino. I will select ch0-ch15 in turn and pass the selected channel to A0 on arduino to do AD Convert.

Then I only connected ch0 to 5V on arduino and selected all channels in turn to do a test. The result shows that when ch1-ch15 is selected, some of those channels will have a output around 5V and those "wrong channels" are fixed if you choose a fixed input channel. However when I connected a 1kΩ resistor between the output of CD4067 and the GND. Those unselected channels' voltage will be 0. And the voltage of ch0 will be around 4.2v. (I checked the connection and code which are correct.)

So after this, I changed the analog input to a piezoelectric film's signal. A similar problem exists. And I tried several kinds of resistors(max at 4MΩ), but the problem still exists.

I have no ideal about why this happened? And I am a little bit confused about some flaws about the CMOS. What is the possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect the unused channels to some particular voltage, not leave them floating.

You are violating the 10K\$\Omega\$ maximum source impedance requirement for the microcontroller by leaving them floating so you will get a reading that depends on the previous channel selection and other things.

Adding a resistor on the output of the multiplexer is not a very good idea, as you have found, because not only does the multiplexer have significant internal resistance (around 500\$\Omega\$ typically) but it varies significantly with input voltage and with temperature.

So, don't connect anything other than the ADC input to the output of the mux and don't leave the analog inputs floating if you want the ADC to give you a sensible reading. There are no bugs here.

Because of the 10K maximum source impedance, you probably should not expect to use a piezo sensor directly with the micro, you may need a high impedance buffer amplifier (unless you can parallel the sensor with 10K and still get enough signal to be useful).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,Spehro. I did an experiment. I created a 0.1v voltage by connecting +5v, a 47k and a 1k impedance in series. Then I connect the unused channels to that voltage. However, the problem still existed.BTW, I will connect each channel with a piezoelectric film at last. This is just a test to make sure those channels will not overlap with each other

Comment: Sorry I left some unusued channels floating too. It does work. Thanks very much. So if I connected all channels to piezoelectric films. Do I still need to connect them with a particular voltage?

Comment: If the piezo film looks like less than 10K then there is no problem, but I doubt that is true. You may need an op-amp or buffer transistor per input channel.

Comment: By using op-amp, do you mean voltage follower or maybe something like charge amplifier? If I connect each op-amp to every channel, will I still need to connect them with a particular voltage using summing amplifier ?

Comment: @hustzf This is really a separate question- how to interface a piezo sensor (whatever type you may have) to an ADC with maximum 10K source Z. Probably just an op-amp or JFET follower or something like that per channel and a resistor (maybe M ohm) on the input to keep the DC voltage within reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a little bit confused. I only used A0(just one analog input of the adc) to connect to the output of the multiplexer, thus should the root cause be the multiplexer rather than the adc?(It seems that if you use one more analog input channels connected to the  high source impedance signals,there will be a Channel-to-channel
crosstalk. However I only use A0 to do AD convert.)  I use an oscilloscope to watch the signal of the output of multiplexer and find the output signal has that problem.

Comment: It sounds like your inputs to the mux are *all* >10K source impedance, so the output will be higher again.

Comment: Thus this 10K source impedance rule is not only for ADC but also for mux?

Comment: The ADC sees the sum of the sensor source impedance and the mux. The mux doesn't care, it just connects things with fairly high resistance and provides some unwanted leakage current.

Comment: hi, Spehro. I did an experiment a few days ago. I used a voltage follower on the input to the multiplexer. Then I selected only one channel and press all piezo films, there is no crosstalk. However crosstalk occurs when I selected all channels in turn. But when I connected the input from voltage follower to adc directly, there is no crosstalk even if I selected all channels in turn. What could be the possible reason for that? I have thought about the switch delay and some other possible reasons. But seems unreasonable.